# HTML onUnclick handler?

Tags: javascript, html, input

I want to trigger one handler when an input field is clicked, and another handler when it is deselected (i.e. if someone clicks outside of the field). Is there a way to accomplish this?

The click handler is simple enough:

```
<input onClick={props.clicked}>
```

Is it possible to create an "unclick" handler?

Comment: Asked & answered before, and if you do a web search for "react outside click handler" you can find *many* results and solutions.

Comment: @DrewReese I know I included the "React" tag, but I think the question may still be useful for people looking for a solution outside of React. The "onBlur" answer looks to have solved my problem.

Comment: Are you asking for a non-react-specific outside click handler solution then?

Comment: @DrewReese When I asked I was just looking for something that would solve my problem. Now that an answer has been provided that is not React-specific, I think it would make sense to make the question not specific to React either, so that people not working in React can find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think onBlur event should be suitable for this